# Xetex support for .otf features

Tags: xetex, fontspec

In the .otf fonts where they are present, the Contextual Alternate (calt) and Localized Forms (locl) functions work fine in LibreOffice.

Experiment: I create a `quoteright.fr` glyph with a large bearing and impose a calt because `quoteright` glyph in Italian and in French is replaced by `quoteright.fr` glyph.

With LibreOffice the difference is evident: for the first line I set the Italian language, for the second line the English language (without bearing):

[image]

Instead with Xetex I can not enable these functions.

If I do not specify anything in the font features, the contextual substitution rule does not work.

If I enter `Contextuals = Alternate` I receive the message:

```
Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Contextuals = Alternate' (calt) not
(fontspec) available for font 'GaramondPremPro' with script
(fontspec) 'Latin' and language 'Default'.
```

and again the contextual replacement rule does not work.

Here is Xetex (first line in Italian, second in English

[image]

with the following code:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\begin{document}

I'I N'P

\begin{english}I'I N'P\end{english}
\end {document}
```

What can you depend on? Is there an error or a lack in my code?

Thank you

**PS**

otfinfo -f recognizes only system-wide features, and not localized ones (neither calt nor locl), that are also present in the font if I check it with FontLab or FontForge:

samiel@darkstar:~/work$ otfinfo --features font.otf

```
aalt    Access All Alternates
c2sc    Small Capitals From Capitals
cpsp    Capital Spacing
dnom    Denominators
frac    Fractions
kern    Kerning
liga    Standard Ligatures
lnum    Lining Figures
numr    Numerators
onum    Oldstyle Figures
pnum    Proportional Figures
smcp    Small Capitals
sups    Superscript
tnum    Tabular Figures
zero    Slashed Zero
```

**PS2**

I tried various possibilities. The following one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,Language=Italian,RawFeature={+calt}]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\begin{document}

I'I N'P

\begin{english}I'I N'P\end{english}

\end{document}
```

produces the calt all over the document, not only for Italian and French languages (as in the font *localized* calt rule).

If I set

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,RawFeature={+calt}]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
```

the replacement is never produced

Added answer to wrong question:

I tried various possibilities. The following one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,Language=Italian,RawFeature={+calt}]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\begin{document}

I'I N'P

\begin{english}I'I N'P\end{english}

\end{document}
```

produces the calt all over the document, not only for Italian and Frenc (as inthe font cal rule.

If I set

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,RawFeature={+calt}]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
```

the replacement is never produced

Comment: did you try to change the language? `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,Language=Italian]{GaramondPremPro}`?

Comment: Yes, but nothing chages. It takes general font settings and not calt

Comment: Well without the font it is difficult to test. If your feature needs locl you could activate it with the RawFeature key.

Comment: I happens with all other otf I tried

Comment: If you know a free font which can be used for tests, add the info to the question.

Comment: try this one: [url]https://www.dropbox.com/s/09yh9lpoejtod0y/SamielPro.otf?dl=0[/url]

Answer (score 5):

The font in your comment works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Language=Italian]{SamielPro.otf}
\setsansfont[]{SamielPro.otf}

\begin{document}

I'I N'P

\sffamily 
I'I N'P


\end{document}
```

[image]

With lualatex it doesn't work, there one need to add the calc-feature explicitly:

```
\setmainfont[Language=Italian,RawFeature=+calt]{SamielPro.otf}
```

A language depending call could be setup with babel and \babelfont:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=TeX]{SamielPro.otf}

% for luatex:
%\babelfont[italian]{rm}[RawFeature=+calt,Ligatures=TeX]{SamielPro.otf}

\begin{document}

I'I N'P

\selectlanguage{english}
I'I N'P

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your usage of  \sfamily

Comment: I simply wanted the two variant under different commands.

Comment: but if I've an Italian or French text and an English one? Why specifying the languages as in my exemples above it doesn't work? It's not a sans but a serif font.... I'm rather confused

Comment: In LibreOffice all works fine, according to the chosen language, according to the sense of contextual substitution (calt) based on language, French or Italian on one side, all other languages on other side...

Comment: I added an example for language dependant switches - but it assumes that the low level call in my first example actually works.

Comment: All your code works, thank you! Only a last question: you use to babel. In this case is it impossible to use polyglossia?

Comment: Well one could something similar with polyglossia perhaps too - but babel has the better interface, and it is better maintained, so I would recommend it anyway.

Comment: ok thank you! PS there a lot of disussion about babel vs polyglossia for xetex ....

Comment: After a deeper testing, I realized that your solution causes other troubles. Xetex does recognize no more a lot of features: `Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Numbers=Lowercase' (onum) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'SamielPro/BI' with
(fontspec)                script 'Latin' and language 'Italian'.

)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/SamielPro(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/SamielPro(0)/m/n' instead on input line 
43` and so on...

Comment: Well the warning seems to be wrong, the numbers are oldstyle. Make a bug report at the fontspec site.

Comment: but I've no more smallcaps, no more oldstyle proportional numbers (only monospaced), no more lining numbers... Ok, I'll write to the fontspec site