# Babel / LuaTex support for .otf features

Tags: luatex, babel

Referring to this thread:
[Xetex support for .otf features](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467943/xetex-support-for-otf-features/), following the indications obtained I modified the code adopting Babel and compiling with LuaTex. In effect this way the Contextual Alternates settings of the font were respected.
However, for some days, after some updates of Texlive, it seems that these settings have been lost. It is no coincidence that I now receive the notice again:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Language 'English' not available for font
(fontspec)                '<myfont>' with script 'Latin'.
```

The font is fine, since the Calt are made with Libreoffice

Or did I commit myself, without realizing, any new errors in the code or did anything change in Babel / Luatex?

The basic code settings are the following ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\babelfont[italian]{rm}[Language=Default,Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{myfont}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Language=English,Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{myfont}
```

Comment: Tomorrow there should be a fontspec update correcting a bug regarding script. Then try again.

Comment: Ah ok; so it seems to be a bug... Thank you

Comment: I received the today update of Babel, but it still doesn't work for some font script as calt. It applies only default settings, not the localized ones

Comment: I wrote about a fontspec update, not babel. And I can't test now, it will have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: I received a new update for fontspec this morning, but the problem is still present

Comment: Then (if you have fontspec 2.7a) your language settings are  probably really wrong. Check with otfinfo.

Comment: I discovered the cause. The following code works fine: `\babelfont[italian]{rm}[RawFeature=+calt,Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{myfont.otf}` and
`\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{myfont.otf}`. On the contrary, this causes that calt are not applied: `\babelfont[italian]{rm}[Language=Default,Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{myfont}` and 
`\babelfont[english]{rm}[Language=English,Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{myfont}`. Is there anything misleading in set `Language=Default` etc?